# Minimal Polynomial Properties

Tags: ring-theory, minimal-polynomials

If $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then can there be another polynomial $g$ of smaller degree than $f$, but not monic having $\alpha$ as a root ?

for example the function $\phi:\frac{R[T]}{(f)}\to R[\alpha]$, if $g$ is of the form $g=h\cdot f+r$ and is mapped to $0$ then $r(\alpha)=0$ but why necessarily $r=0$ ?

Comment: Have  you   even  properly  gone  through  the  definition  of  "minimal  polynomial" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a field, a minimal polynomial can always be taken to be monic: just divide by the leading coefficient.  Over a ring, there might be no nonzero monic polynomial at all with $\alpha$ as a root.  Consider e.g. algebraic numbers that are not algebraic integers.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are talking about for example for a number field say $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$,  $\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic integer but no rational number of the form $x/y$, and the same is valid for my case; if I find an irreducible polynomial, not monic with $\alpha$ as a root, then $\alpha$ would not have a minimal polynomial, am I right ?

Comment: $\alpha$ would have a minimal polynomial, but not a **monic** minimal polynomial.  For example, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}/2$ **over $\mathbb Z$** is $2 X^2 - 1$.  The minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ is $X^2 - 1/2$, but that has a coefficient that is not in $\mathbb Z$.